# Retrieving user data from facebook api using facebook-node-sdk nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to retrieve my fb post's through fb api using nodejs and while doing that iam getting the following error.. can anyone help me?

I have tried 'facebook-node-sdk'
Kindly suggest how to retrieve data from fb.Since im new i do know the proper way.

```
import express from 'express';
import axios from 'axios';
const router = express.Router();
const app = require('express')();
var Facebook = require('facebook-node-sdk');

var facebook = new Facebook({ appID: 'appid', secret: 'secretid' });

router.get('/facebook', (req, res) => {

    let url = "http://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/me?&access_token=myaccesstoken";
    facebook.api(url, function(err, data){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);

    }
    else{
        res.json({
            statusCode: 200,
            status: "Success1",
            result: data,
            message:"fb data"
        })
        //Do some stuff with the data object
    }
});
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/SJPurusoth/sociall-wall  here is my code for retrieving fb data!!

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: Please don't use an external GitHub repository to show your code. It's not guaranteed to be static, it's not immediately obvious where your issue is, and not everyone will be able to or be willing to view your code to solve your issue. Instead, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of the code that is causing your issue.

Comment: @Akaisteph7  [Error: Error validating application. Invalid application ID.]
  result:{ error: {message: 'Error validating application. Invalid application ID.',
type: 'OAuthException',code: 190, fbtrace_id: 'AW9q_hiolzVvVNneJpOZ7in' } },
code: 0, message: 'Error validating application. Invalid application ID.' }

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut ok sir